# I want to completely redo my thesis without repeating the research course. Has anyone had a similar experience?

Tags: thesis, thesis-committee

I have completed all but one course (which is tied to the final three chapters of my thesis) for my M.Ed. My research was designed back when I was teaching and I designed an experiment for use in my own classroom. I had to postpone conducting my research (and graduating) because my family relocated and I had a baby. I now want to finish my Master's, but am unable to complete my research, and would like to choose another topic altogether.

I would like the be able to start from scratch, write the first three chapters of my paper outside of school, return for my last research course, take my comprehensive exams, and graduate. Does anyone have any experience with a similar situation? Of course, I realize that this is likely a school-specific question, however, are there any users that have had a similar experience?

I know there must someone who has had to change their research question at a similar point in their program of study; I would love to hear how your situation was resolved before I speak with my advisor about this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, you should precise where you are preparing your diploma (the U.S.?), this kind of stuff is highly country-dependent.

Comment: What does your advisor say?

Comment: "I realize that this may be a school-specific question, but I'm wondering if I may not be thinking this through." - in my place, a Master's degree involves various classes with associated exams, and once you have passed all of these, you can, at any time, pick a topic for your Master thesis and work on it for up to 6 months. So ... what you propose seems (all regulations etc. aside) feasible. However, I suspect this statement isn't going to help you, because, as you say, things are very much dependent on the respective university rules. Thus, the question should really be narrowed down.

Comment: You really need to first ask your examinations office or similar what they allow you to do – that’s what they are for. We do not know their regulations (if they cover such a case at all) and we also do not know how exactly your degree program is structured. All we can do right now is provide guesses, all of which can turn out to be false. Once you have acquired this information, you could possibly ask here about pros and cons of some actual choices you have – but even then somebody with detailed knowledge of your situation and your program should be able to provide better answers than we do.

Comment: Thank you; again, I knew when I asked the question that I would ultimately have to consult my school's office of graduate studies, however I was really hoping that someone out there would have had a similar situation that give me an idea of what to expect. 

I am working the United States, to the user that asked. 
I have not consulted my advisor yet; I wanted to, as I said, have a general idea of what he would say in this situation.

Answer (score 7):

In all of the Masters programs that I have encountered, the specifics of one's thesis are largely unrelated to the classroom courses that you have taken. As such, changing thesis topics would not be any problem as long as you have (or can find) and advisor who approves of the new topic.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, but I've also never heard of anyone who just up and changed their topic half way through writing their thesis. Thanks!